# Rails redirect with https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, https, relative-path

I'm maintaining a Ruby on Rails site and I'm confused as to how to perform redirects to relative URLs using the https protocol.

I can successfully create a redirect to a relative URL using http, for example:

```
redirect_to "/some_directory/"
```

But I cannot discern how to create a redirect to a URL using the https protocol. I have only been able to do so by using absolute URLS, for example:

```
redirect_to "https://mysite.com/some_directory/"
```

I would like to keep my code clean, and using relative URLs seems like a good idea. Does anyone know how to achieve this in Rails?

Comment: Can I get a clarification on your question.  Do you want to force people to always use HTTPS on your site or only for some URLS?  Be default RAILS will continue to use the HTTPS if the current request is HTTPS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably better off using [`ssl_requirement`](http://rubygems.org/gems/ssl_requirement) and not caring if a link or redirect is or isn't using https. With ssl_requirement, you declare which actions require SSL, which ones are capable of SSL and which ones are required not to use SSL.

If you're redirecting somewhere outside of your Rails app, then specifying the protocol as Olly suggests will work.

Comment: These days look at `force_ssl`, available in rails 3.1 and above.

Comment: Matt if you made your comment a separate answer, I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 41):

The `ActionController::Base#redirect_to` method takes an options hash, one of the parameters of which is `:protocol` which allows you to call:

```
redirect_to :protocol => 'https://', 
            :controller => 'some_controller', 
            :action => 'index'
```

See the definition for [`#redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000662) and [`#url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000649) for more info on the options.

---

Alternatively, and especially if SSL is to be used for all your controller actions, you could take a more declarative approach using a `before_filter`.  In `ApplicationController` you could define the following method:

```
def redirect_to_https
    redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless (request.ssl? || request.local?)
end
```

You can then add filters in your those controllers which have actions requiring SSL, e.g:

```
class YourController
    before_filter :redirect_to_https, :only => ["index", "show"]
end
```

Or, if you require SSL across your entire app, declare the filter in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController
    before_filter :redirect_to_https
end
```

Comment: You can use `:protocol => 'https://'` iff you are passing a hash to `redirect_to` if you are passing a relative URL like in the question above, that will not work. I agree that a `before_filter` is the better way to go in general.

Comment: Be careful with this, the redirect will drop all the parameters. If you wants to redirect **JUST FOR** the protocol, you should call like this:
`redirect_to({:protocol => "https://"}.merge(request.parameters))`

Answer (score 38):

If you want your *entire application* to be served over https then since **Rails 4.0** the best way to do this is to enable `force_ssl` in the configuration file like so:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # [..]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security,
  # and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

By default this option is already present in `config/environments/production.rb` in in newly generated apps, but is commented out.

As the comment says, this will not just redirect to https, but also sets the `Strict-Transport-Security` header ([HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)) and makes sure that the secure flag is set on all cookies. Both measures increase the security of your application without significant drawbacks. It uses [`ActionDispatch:SSL`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2468b161a6ada171cceeddaf418b540eb98f2d55/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb).

The HSTS expire settings are set to a year by default and doesn't include subdomains, which is probably fine for most applications. You can configure this with the `hsts` option:

```
config.hsts = {
  expires: 1.month.to_i,
  subdomains: false,
}
```

---

If you're running **Rails 3 (>=3.1)** or don't want to use https for the entire application, then you can use the [`force_ssl`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html#method-i-force_ssl) method in a controller:

```
class SecureController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl
end
```

That's all. You can set it per controller, or in your `ApplicationController`. You can force https conditionally using the familiar `if` or `unless` options; for example:

```
# Only when we're not in development or tests
force_ssl unless: -> { Rails.env.in? ['development', 'test'] }
```

Comment: force_ssl is not a great option if you are developing behind a tunnel. For example, an ngrok tls tunnel allows you to specify a cert. Then ngrok terminates the tls connection with the specified cert and forwards unencrypted to your app (so your app thinks everything is http). This means you don't have to setup an nginx proxy and do https on your development box.

Comment: @MichaelJohnston This is why you can use `unless` to not force SSL in dev (see the last line in my answer).

Comment: @MichaelJohnston this should only be turned on in the production environment and will not impact your local development setup

Comment: AWS allows you to terminate SSL at the load balancer. Which then forwards unencrypted data to the EC2 instances (where your app is deployed). Unfortunately, `force_ssl` isnt a good option here, even with the `unless` condition specified above

Answer (score 3):

If you want to globally controll the protocol of urls generated in controllers, you can override the url_options method in you application controller. You could force the protocol of the generated urls depending on the rails env like so :

```
 def url_options
    super
    @_url_options.dup.tap do |options|
      options[:protocol] = Rails.env.production? ? "https://" : "http://"
      options.freeze
    end
  end
```

this example works in rails 3.2.1, i'm not exactly sure for earlier or future versions.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is somewhat tangential to the original question, but I record it in case others end up here in similar circumstances to myself.

I had a situation where I needed to have Rails use `https` proto in url helpers etc. even though the origin of all requests is unencrypted (`http`).

Now, ordinarily in this situation (which is normal when Rails is behind a reverse proxy or load balancer etc.), the `x-forwarded-proto` header is set by the reverse proxy or whatever, so even though requests are unencrypted between the proxy & rails (probably not advisable in production by the way) rails thinks everything is in `https`.

I needed to run behind an ngrok tls tunnel. I wanted to have ngrok terminate the tls with letsencrypt certificates I specified. However when it does so, ngrok does not offer the ability to customize headers, including setting `x-forwarded-proto` (although this feature is planned at some point in the future).

The solution turned out to be quite simple: Rails does not depend on either the protocol of the origin or whether `x-forwarded-proto` is set directly, but on the Rack env var `rack.url_scheme`. So I just needed to add this Rack middleware in development:

```
class ForceUrlScheme
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env['rack.url_scheme'] = 'https'
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force ALL traffic via `https`, then the best way in Rails 6 is to configure `production.rb` with:

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

If you need a more flexible solution, you can handle it with a simple before_action filter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  include SessionsHelper
  include LandingpageHelper
  include ApplicationHelper
  include UsersHelper
  include OrganisationHelper

  before_action :enforce_ssl, :except => [:health] 

  def enforce_ssl
    if ENV['ENFORCE_SSL'].to_s.eql?('true') && !request.ssl?
      redirect_to request.url.gsub(/http/i, "https")
    end
  end 


end
```

If you run your application on AWS ECS Fargate with health checks, then you need a more flexible solution because the health check from the AWS target group is not invoked via https. Of course, you want the health check to work and at the same time, you want to force SSL for all other controller methods.

The `ENFORCE_SSL` is just an environment variable that turns this feature on/off.

Comment: If it is just for health checking or metrics endpoints, you an still use `config.force_ssl = true` and then use `config.ssl_options = { redirect: { exclude: -> request { /healthcheck/.match?(request.path) } } }` in order to exclude requests to the healthcheck from redirection to SSL.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 one can use the `force_ssl_redirect` before_action to enforce ssl for a single controller. Please note that by using this method your cookies won't be marked as secure and [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is not used.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last sentence?  For someone unfamiliar with 'marking cookies as secure' and HSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `protocol` to `..._url`:

```
redirect_to your_url(protocol: 'https')
```

or with `subdomain`:

```
redirect_to your_url(protocol: 'https', subdomain: 'your_subdomain')
```

Answer (score -2):

Relative URLs, by definition, use the current protocol and host. If you want to change the protocol being used, you need to supply the absolute URL. I would take Justice's advice and create a method that does this for you:

```
def redirect_to_secure(relative_uri)
  redirect_to "https://" + request.host + relative_uri
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Open the class that has `redirect_to` and add a method `redirect_to_secure_of` with an appropriate implementation. Then call:

```
redirect_to_secure_of "/some_directory/"
```

Put this method in the `lib` directory or somewhere useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a little more detail than "an appropriate implementation."

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking how to make the *calling* code clean.