# Rails URL helpers return non-https URLs though default_url_options set to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have Nginx serving the SSL. On the rails side it's a Puma and I have
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { protocol: 'https', host: example.com` but my `root_url` still returns `http://example.com`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` in your nginx config so Rails would see your request as HTTPS.
Here is another issue that is caused by absence of this header - `force_ssl` would cause endless redirection: [https redirect for rails app behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432266/https-redirect-for-rails-app-behind-proxy)

UPDATE:
X-Forwarded-* headers are considered *legacy* now. Consider using `Forwarded`
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: can you share ur complete nginx config? where to put this proxy_set_header ?

Comment: @buncis here is a general config example http://nginx.org/en/docs/example.html Here is a newer solution btw (I've updated the answer) https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/