# Trying to force ssl, getting "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, https

I'm trying to force all urls generated by my controller to be "https" and redirecting to https otherwise. I tried the method explained in [this blog](http://lucastej.blogspot.com/2008/01/ruby-on-rails-how-to-set-urlfor.html) and the one suggested by Olly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662262/rails-redirect-with-https)
and I'm getting this error if I try to access my application:

> **This webpage has a redirect loop**
>
> The webpage at https://'example.com' has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing
>   your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem.
>   If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with
>   your computer.

Clearing the cookie doesn't help. Why is it going into a loop? I made sure to run the code under condition that request.ssl is false. I'm using Rails 2.3.10. 
So here is what I tried, in my application controller I added:

```
     url_for unless (Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?) 
     def default_url_options(options) 
    { :only_path => false, :protocol => 'https' } unless (Rails.env.test? ||  Rails.env.development?) 
    end
```

I also tried

```
def redirect_to_https
  redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless (request.ssl? || Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development? || local_request?)
end
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the code that handles this in your application? It most likely is because you don't test if the request is already SSL though

Comment: Edited my question to show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain I'm using is shared among different apps so the request is received by the apache server and is forwarded to the app server so enforcing ssl in this way doesn't work because the app sees the request as "local" and always over http so it goes into a redirect loop. I will enforce https on the server level instead.